# Can Javascript Web Workers affect the DOM?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out if I can write javascript that is within an worker to interact with the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they cannot. They can only return "messages" back to the main script, which can then interact with the DOM.

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_web_workers